Does Module Federation work with Next 14 standalone build?
I'm trying to build a micro fe project with next 14 project, and I was wondering whether is possible or not to make work Module Federation with Next 14 standalone build option.
I've been trying to make it work, but I feel like I'm missing something. I couldn't find anything that says explicitly whether MF works with a standalone build or not, and maybe I'm not that good at understanding the underlying MF stack.
Here is the demo repo I've been playing so far:
https://github.com/Staslios/federated-next-monorepo
Once the standalone build is finished everything is inside .next/standalone folder as expected (duh?) and yes the remotes are being generated but they are outside the 'standalone' folder, and of course if I try to run my next apps with node server.js yes apps as single entities will work but remotes won't.
Should I stop considering the standalone folder as the only folder that holds my node server and start considering also the .next/static/chunks and .next/static/ssr folders in order to make it work? Or should I move everything inside a standalone folder ta build time? Or am I missing some crucial documentation?
